# adding a class and an id to and elements created by loop js

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying here to add a class and an id to the elements that will be created (div or section) ,
the problem is when I tried to make a variable that contains the elements that will be created but the code didn't work

```js
let numberOfElements = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].onchange = function () {
  numberOfElements = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
}
///

let theTextInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value;
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].onchange = function () {
  theTextInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value
}

let theSubmit = document.getElementsByName("create")[0];
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function (e) {
  // stop submitting
    e.preventDefault();
};
theSubmit.onclick = function () {

  if (document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value === "Div") {
    for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfElements; i++) {
      return  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div")).innerHTML = theTextInput;;
    }
  } else if (document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value !== "Div"){
    for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfElements; i++) {
      return  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("section")).innerHTML = theTextInput;;
    }
  }
};
```

```html
  <body>
    <form action="">
      <input type="number" name="elements" class="input" placeholder="Number Of Elements" value="1"/>
      <input type="text" name="texts" class="input" placeholder="Elements Text" />
      <select name="type" class="input" >
        <option value="Div">Div</option>
        <option value="Section">Section</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" name="create" value="Create" />
      <div class="results"></div>
    </form>

    <!-- /////////// -->
    <script src="DOM.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: The `return` in your `for` loops there makes little sense - that will end execution and return from the function directly in the _first_ loop iteration.

Comment: This is a problem you would not have, if you did _not_ try to cram as much code as possible into one line. `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div")).innerHTML = theTextInput;` - do these steps after each other. `let newElement = document.createElement("div"); newElement.innerHTML = ...; newElement.id = ...; newElement.className = ...; document.body.appendChild(newElement);`

Comment: (Since you are appending the element to body, you could also use `document.body.lastChild` to access the one you just appended, and then add class and ID that way. But taking apart that one-liner is still the better idea.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can use variable for created element and update whatever property/attribute required on that variable. At the same time remove the `return` on creating elements to continue create the rest. The `return` will stop once first element created:

```
const divElm = document.createElement('div');
```

Now, you can modify that element as required then add to the DOM:

```
divElm.innerHTML = theTextInput;
divElm.classList.add('new-class');
document.body.append(divElm);
```

Your code can be simplified by getting the required number and text values from inputs only when you need to create the elements. The inputs `change` events aren't required. Just merge the `submit` and `click` events into a single one, then add the get required values inside it:

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function (e) {
  // stop submitting
  e.preventDefault();
  const numberOfElements = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
  const theTextInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1].value;

  if (document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value === "Div") {
    for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfElements; i++) {
      const divElm = document.createElement('div');
      divElm.innerHTML = theTextInput;
      divElm.classList.add('new');
      document.body.append(divElm);
    }
  } else if (document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value !== "Div") {
    for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfElements; i++) {
      // Same code as above but with section
      ...
    }
  }
};
```

Even with that, there's still room for improvement. So, try to split your statements into multiple lines. First, store queried elements into variables/arrays then use them to manipulate the element. That will also reduce the number of times you query/get those elements from the DOM